# Install actual version during beta/alpha test (Android)

Tags: android, testing, beta-testing, google-developers-console

I would like someone else to test a migration process of my app.

My App actually has version 10.

My App published to Alpha has version 11.

I added the tester to the list of Alpha testers and he can install the new version 11 successfully.

Now the question :
How can my tester install the older version 10, even the tester is in the list of alpha testers, without removing him from the Alpha-Testers list ?
Are there 2 different links, where we can install both the newer and older version without manipulating the list of testers ?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is not possible [because it only depends on version codes,  the highest will be installed](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213#availability):

> Alpha testing group users are eligible for the alpha, beta, or
>   production version of your app (**with the highest version code** that's
>   compatible with their device). Beta testing group users are only
>   eligible for the beta or production version of your app (with the
>   highest version code that's compatible with their device).
>
> This means your alpha APKs should have the highest version codes,
>   followed by beta, and finally production.
>
> If a beta APK is uploaded with a higher version code than an alpha
>   APK, alpha users who can install both will install the beta APK
>   instead of the alpha APK.
>
> If a production APK is uploaded with a
>   higher version code than an alpha or beta APK, some or all of your
>   alpha and beta users will install the production APK, instead of APKs
>   of the testing tracks.

I thought that perhaps using Beta and Alpha channels but I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39737237/1009132):

> Another difference is that alpha test APK's version code should be
>   higher than beta test one. If you upload a higher version of APK on beta
>   test channel, alpha test will automatically be closed. (This principle
>   applies for production APK too. APK version code should be 'Production
>   < Beta < Alpha'.)

Adding the same tester to Beta and Alpha and trying something like this:

Prod version with same code than Beta and version code 10

Beta version with same code than Prod and version code 11

The tester can install Beta version.

Upload Alpha version with code under test and version code 12

The tester can update to Alpha version and test migration.

If all correct, upload Prod version with tested code and version code 13

And upload Beta version with same code than Prod and version code 14

The tester can install Beta version.

Add feature to test and upload Alpha version with version code 15

The tester can update to Alpha version and test migration.

...