# How to test an app before post it on Google Play

Tags: android, apk

Before I post my app  on Google Play, I would like some friends test it to me, so if there's anything to change, I could do it BEFORE post it. How can I do that? My colleagues  told me I should use a link from apk.

Remember: I don't want to use a cellphone as an emulator. I want people from other countries to test it for me (it's a multilingual app)

Comment: So to confirm, you want users to run your app without posting it on google play?

Comment: Why didn't you ask your colleagues how they'd like the APK? Hint : you can email it

Comment: You can do alpha and beta testing through Google Play (before making it available in the Play Store): https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en

Comment: Make world-wide friends and tell them to test it Or find any multi-national company which  can do test for your app. AFAIK, there is no other way for test by multinational people on real device.

Comment: Yes, I want to people use my app without post it on Google Play. Let me explain better: it's a multilingual app for foreign people who come to Brazil. I'm doing this project to my final project in college, that's why I need to test it before post on Play Store: because I want to know if the translation of the 4 languages are correct. For this, I'll ask some foreign friends to confirm everything is okay, and only later I'll post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to share your app is to upload it in a cloud. Any cloud as long as your friends can access it. Send the link to them or you attach the apk on an e-mail and send it to them.

Answer (score 3):

There are three ways to upload your apk on Google play store.

1. Upload your apk in **Alpha** testing, where you can create a link for your apk and can manually share this link to the people you want.
2. Upload your apk in **Beta** testing, Here your apk will be uploaded on play store for testing, where everyone can see your application and test it. Here anyone can provide feedback.
3. Upload your apk in **Production**, Here you finally upload your apk.

This is a short description if you want to know more, follow this link
[Difference between alpha and beta testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20984120/need-some-clarification-about-beta-alpha-testing-on-the-developer-console)

In your case, I think you should upload your apk in beta testing.