# Test google play services without uploading the APK

Tags: android, testing, google-play, google-play-services

I'm currently working on an game app and trying to setup achievements with GooglePlay Game Services. Now my problem is, that I have to upload the apk every time I make an change. This slows down the developing process tremendous. So my question: Can I test my changes without uploading the APK to the Test Track? I tried it, but there occurs an "Google Play not authenticated" error. Maybe I can sign my app with the GooglePlay key?

Answer (score 0):

You may publish your app in Alpha/Beta states. Based from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20984120/need-some-clarification-about-beta-alpha-testing-on-the-developer-console), by default, only production is available on the Play Store. However, you can now add an option in your Play Store page for users to opt into an open Beta program. [Source.](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?p=open_beta&rd=1#open_beta)

Comment: Yep I did that already. But the problem in my case is uploading itself. So when I try to fix a bug and test it, I've to upload it every time to an internal test track. And due my slow internet this process takes more than 30mins. So my question is: can I test features containing GooglePlay Game Services without uploading the apk and just by installing it on my android device?