# will open testing on Google Play overwrite the existing production app?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

So we already have our application in production, available to all users.
We have developed an overhaul of this application, and we would like to set it available for open testing.

My question is: if we setup this open testing, will it overwrite the existing app on the play store (then user won't be able to download the actual production app), or will it be available on a separate link?

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by open testing??

Comment: I mean "Open testing" in the Google Play Console. (I updated the post)

Comment: this might help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20984120/need-some-clarification-about-beta-alpha-testing-on-the-developer-console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Production Application will remain as your old version.
Production App will be available for the global users. Open Testing will not overwrite the production util you switched from the release manager.