# Is SQLite data lost when moving an Android App from Internal Testing to Closed Testing in the Play Console

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I have been testing my app using internal testing on google play but wanted to move it into closed testing so I can get more information and have a better sense of how to manage the app when in production, test [in-app updates](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates) (doesn't seem to be working with internal testing), and I want more control over updates as I seem to have to wait an long time (really unknown time) for the update to come through ([see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66618739/google-play-not-updating-internal-app-automatically)).

I can't use uninstall/re-install as there is data on the app which users need. Is this required when moving?

I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66550055/meaning-of-open-testing-in-playstore) about the difference between internal testing and closed testing, which was helpful but did not know the impact on an end user when moving from internal testing to closed testing.

[The documentation](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9845334?hl=en#zippy=%2Ccan-i-run-multiple-tests-per-app-at-the-same-time) states:

> If a user opts to your app's internal test, they're no longer eligible
> to receive the open or closed test. To regain access to the open or
> closed test, the user must opt-out of the internal test and back into
> the open or closed test.

If the end user opts-out of the internal testing, and has a Room/SQLite database, does the app stay on the phone and get updated through closed testing, or is the app removed and all the data lost?